# saving files without showdialog

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I want to save many files, almost 200. When i'm saving only a few i'm doing it this way:

```
                    dialog.Filter = "Bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";
                    dialog.FileName = name + "_copy";
                    dialog.ShowDialog();
                    bitmap1.Save(dialog.FileName);
```

How can i do the same but without using dialog.showdialog() ?

Comment: How do you want to choose the file names?

Answer (score 7):

Look at your code.  The Save method takes a string argument, i.e., the file path.  You obviously don't need the user to enter that, you can simply provide your own path.

```
 bitmap1.Save(@"C:\foo.bmp");
```

You haven't provided much info, so perhaps your problem is knowing where to actually save the files?  If you don't need user input (i.e., you don't want to use a FileDialog), then you will need to determine some scheme for organizing these files.